# Create Partitioned Table from Partitioned Table - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a partitioned table A.

```sql
create table A (
col1 timestamp,
col2 int
)
partition by col2;

create table partition1 partition of A from values (minvalue) to (y);
create table partition1 partition of A from values (y) to (maxvalue);
copy A from '/some/csv/file'
```

The above code gives me a paritioned table A with the data populated. I want to create another table using -

```sql
create table B as (
select *,
col2 * 3 as col3 -- Add a  new column 
from A
);
```

Can I save A as a partitioned CSV/'insert_format' file?

Is it possible that B is also paritioned the same way A is?

Comment: That's what views are for. By the way, your original `CREATE TABLE` statement is a syntax error.

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe can you tell me how to get that done?

Comment: You say `CREATE VIEW B` instead of `CREATE TABLE B`.